# Do you use the plastic buckets for purposes other than organizing your bricks?

Tags: piece-information, storage

We have several bucket sets like #5560.

Now that our collection is growing, it's becoming harder to find what we need in the buckets even though we have them sorted by color. Plus they are in a rather tall, wobbly stack in a corner and they keep getting knocked over.

So I'm thinking of organizing the bricks into small drawers and getting rid of the buckets entirely. But that leaves me with a million ugly pink and blue buckets that have no purpose.

I'm big on repurposing items rather than throwing them away. So tell me: what can I use these buckets for rather than storing LEGO bricks?

Comment: "What can I use these buckets for rather than storing LEGO bricks?" Do you want to use these buckets for uses other than storing LEGO or storing stuff in general?

Comment: anything!  I just don't want to throw them in the landfill/ocean or have them sitting around taking up space.  They no longer work for storing/organizing lego bricks so I want to give them another purpose.

Comment: Theoretically you could use them as an inner support structure for large scale buildings like mountains or warehouses. I have no experience with it but it would technically keep such a large build 100% LEGO, while reducing its cost and weight.

Comment: I wish I had enough Lego to justify something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPDolqztmBc)

Answer (score 1):

Well the buckets themselves have value.
If you can't use them you could sell them to people who want them.

Your example set #5560 has an original box only listing on BrickLink, as do many other of the brick boxes, run a search for "brick box" you'll find lots.

The prices vary from a few dollars, to ~$20 for you example. They don't seem to be big sellers, but there are some sales.

If you have a lot of them and/or you want them gone quicker set up an eBay listing for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't sell them making sand castles with them is an option I suppose. I would stick them in the loft for the future though if it were me. Simply because if you ever sell your LEGO boxed sets are always better and command a higher price.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find them very useful for storing bricks, but have used them as interim storage during a massive sorting project.  Also used 2 to grow tomatoes last year, but they tipped over frequently.  Best use I've found is as a small wastepaper basket.  (I recycle most paper, but I don't know what else to call a small trash receptacle.)